# Programmatically connecting to Quickbooks Online on a Mac

Tags: python, macos, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I'm looking to programmatically connect to QuickBooks Online using a Python script. I understand that the SDK is not available for the Mac platform. Is there a simple way for me to do http post of qbXML? Any Python libraries that make it easier?

Answer (score 4):

I already answered your question over here:

- https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=7&threadid=15018&enterthread=y

There's a ton of documentation on my wiki on this:

- http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_online_edition

For QuickBooks Online, there's absolutely no reason you need the SDK- it doesn't give you anything except for some (pain in the butt to use) COM objects which generate qbXML requests. It's actually easier to just generate qbXML requests with straight Python instead.

Once you go through application registration, you can just make HTTP POST requests to:

- https://webapps.quickbooks.com/j/AppGateway

And you'll get back qbXML responses.